# Tapestry5 Value Encoder with Hibernate Composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I'm trying to get my tapestry value encoder to work with a hibernate composite key. I have the following code and I'm trying to get the composite id and pass it to the interface where it could later be sent back to the server for decoding back to an object.

```
@Embeddable
public class IfasvVendorPK implements Serializable{

    @Column(length = 4, nullable = false)
    protected String peId;
    @Column(length = 8, nullable = false)
    protected String peAddrCd;

    public IfasvVendorPK() {
    }

    public IfasvVendorPK(String peId, String peAddrCd) {
        this.peId = peId;
        this.peAddrCd = peAddrCd;
    }
    // equals, hashCode
}

@Entity
public class IfasvVendor implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private IfasvVendorPK ifasvVendorPK;

    //...
}
```

The following is my value encoder. The toClient is where would I need to send the composite key to the interface. I'm not sure how to get the composite key.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public LabelAwareValueEncoder getEncoderVendor() {
    return new LabelAwareValueEncoder<IfasvVendor>() {

        public String toClient(IfasvVendor value) {
            return value.getIfasvVendorPK().toString();
        }

        public IfasvVendor toValue(String clientValue) {
            if (clientValue.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            return (IfasvVendor) session.get(IfasvVendor.class, clientValue);
        }

        public String getLabel(IfasvVendor value) {
            return value.getPeNameU();
        }
    };
}
```

If someone could help me to better understand how to work with the composite key so I could get my value encoder working, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Please show the implementation of toString() in the IfasvVendor class.
2. What is the type of the session variable?
3. Are you sure the IfasvVendor object is available in the session? It is preferable to retrieve it from the datastore than from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has no way to know how what this string means and cannot convert it back.
I suggest adding a non-composite ID or concaternate the values which you then split again in your toValue method.

If you keep the ValueEncoder longer than your request (ex. with @Persist) you could put a HashMap in it to easily get the object back for a concaternated client key;

Since your Composite key is serializeable you could serialize it in toClient and deserialize it in toValue. However, I really wouldn't do that, serializing stuff and sending it to a browser and back is a big, evil security hole.

Comment: I ended up concatenating my values since I changing the database to use a non-composite id wasn't an option. I'm using the method within jumpstart that doesn't use @Persist which seems to work good with the exception of server side validation. Could you elaborate on how serializing could be a big security hole. Thanks.

Comment: to the serializing question: If you serialize the whole object (not just the ID), you kind of open a interface to inject arbitrary objects by simply replacing them with an other serialized object - for example with a object that loggs internal stuff to somewhere. I don't think it's easy, but it's possible to abuse that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your line:

`return (IfasvVendor) session.get(IfasvVendor.class, clientValue);`

At this point, your "clientValue" is a String, as generated by `IfasvVendorPK.toString()`

I'm not sure this should work in hibernate, shouldn't you be passing an instance of `IfasvVendorPK` to `session.get`?

You can test whether this should work with the following:

```
    public String toClient(IfasvVendor value) {

        // test toValue strategy (probably breaks):
        System.out.println(
            session.get(IfasvVendor.class, value.getIfasvVendorPK().toString()));

        // test toValue strategy (probably works):
        System.out.println(
            session.get(IfasvVendor.class, value.getIfasvVendorPK()));

        return value.getIfasvVendorPK().toString();
    }
```

So if I'm right, what you need to do in `toValue` is convert the `String` back to an `IfasvVendorPK` before sending it to `session.get`.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try out your suggestion, I ended up concatenating my compound key for the time being, I'll test your solution soon.